# How to set event type in custom child component from parent component?

Tags: reactjs, events

So, I have a custom, configurable input component which is supposed to be used in few different forms. The "configuration" for the input filed is being handled by the parent components (validations, type of input field, etc.).
The problem is the event type. For example, in one of the forms, I need the event type on the input field to be onBlur and in another form - onKeyDown.
The question is: how can I pass the event type from the parent component which renders the custom input filed?
Disclaimer - I am new to React, quite new to programming and have been looking for a solution for a few days now to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

First, define your component, that holds the `<input />`  (or function)

```
class MyClass extends Component {
  render() {
    // you can extract some of the props if you want to manipulate somehow. Everything else will be saved in rest
    const { value, name, ...rest } = this.props;
    return (
      <input value={value} name={name} {...rest} />
    )
  }
}
```

Then, to that new component, you can add any props, that are available for `<input/>` tag, example:

```
class Test extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <Fragment>
      <MyClass value={5} name="Name" onBlur={this.onBlur} onFocus={this.onFocus} />
      <MyClass value="Hello, world!" id='randomId' onChange={e => console.log(e.target.value)} />
    </Fragment>
    )
  }

  onBlur = e => {
    console.log('Blur');
  }

  onFocus = e => {
    console.log('Focus');
  }
}
```

Now you have two different inputs - one is listening for onBlur and onFocus, the other one has id and listens for onChange.